# Capture Dates from MySQL Workbench database in FastApi

Tags: python, mysql, date, fastapi

I am trying to fetch dates from my MySQL Workbench database. But I get a "None" result in the terminal. How would this be achieved?. I'm trying to use the ORM of FastApi Framework.

Someone can help me please?.

models:

```
class PortabilidadInfo(Base):
      __tablename__ = "portabilidad"
      msisdn = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      operator_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
      last_port = Column(Date, default=datetime.now(), nullable=True)
```

Code:

```
  last_portability = row[7]     # 2022-04-03  06:00:00
  last_portability_obj = datetime.strptime(last_portability, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  print("OBJ FECHA: ", last_portability_obj, type(last_portability_obj))
                        
  ## FETCH DATE DATA FROM DATABASE
  date_info = session.query(PortabilidadInfo).get(last_portability_obj)
  print("XXXXXX: ", date_info, type(date_info))
```

Comment: `last_portability_obj` seems to be formatted datestamp, while `msisdn` - which is your primary key - is an integer. What is your expectation for the return value when you look at the rows present in the database?

Comment: @MatsLindh I just want to fetch/capture the date from the database... 

For example: 

If in the database exist the row[7] = '2020-04-03 06:00:00' , simply give to me and if don't exist return me None, but it's weird because I checked the db and row[7] exists in the db

Comment: In your example `row[7]` seems to be a datetime. Do you mean to search for any rows in the database with that datetime in its `last_port` column?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I will copy the code below.

```
## BUSCO FECHA EN CSV ##
last_portability = row[7]     # 2022-04-03 06:00:00 'str'
print("FECHA CSV: ", last_portability, type(last_portability))

# FETCH DATE DATA FROM DATABASE
date_info = session.query(PortabilidadInfo).filter(
PortabilidadInfo.last_port == last_portability).first()
print("FECHA BDD: ", date_info, type(date_info))


TERMINAL: 

FECHA CSV:  2020-04-23 6:00:00 <class 'str'>

FECHA BDD:  <models.portabilidad.PortabilidadInfo object at 0x7fdc38cc3470> <class 'models.portabilidad.PortabilidadInfo'>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).